# Run git command from an external directory in fish function

Tags: git, fish

In a fish function, can I run a command from a certain directory without changing into it?

*or*

Can I run a git command (`push`) from outside the repository by specifying its path somehow?

---

I'd like to do something like this:

```
function backup
    set BKDIR /flash/drive
    rsync -av $HOME/important/ $BKDIR/important/
    cd $HOME/git_repo
    git push flash master
end
```

But I don't want to change into some other directory. It'd be great if I could sync the git repo like when I use rsync: by specifying the source directory but not changing the working directory.

I suppose a last resort would be to record the current directory at the beginning and change back to it at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git --git-dir /foo/bar/ rest-of-git-command`

ref:

> `--git-dir=<path>` Set the path to the repository. This can also be controlled by setting the GIT_DIR environment variable. It can be an absolute path or relative path to current working directory.

Comment: I've actually found that using `git -C /foo/bar rest-of-git-command` is closer to what I wanted: "`-C <path>`: *Run as if `git` was started in `<path>` instead of the current working directory.*" I think it works better in more cases, as it sets `git-dir` and `work-tree`. See `-C` in [the git man-page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git).

Answer (score 2):

@RaGe has the correct answer.

A fish-specific answer is to use pushd and then popd

```
function backup
    # ...
    pushd $HOME/git_repo
    git push flash master
    popd
end
```